# Which driver should I install for Yii framework to work with MongoDB in WAMP?

Tags: php, mongodb, yii, wamp, yii-extensions

Should I install PHP driver in WAMP to work with MongoDB for YII Framework, OR Yii Driver?

When I google about drivers for mongodb to work with PHP, I get different results from the search of 'mongo driver for Yii'.

What is the difference between them. Which is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use php_mongo.dll php extension as suggested in this tutorial.

http://www.pronique.com/blog/installing-mongodb-on-windows-the-wamp-way

Comment: I have seen this good tutorial to install MongoDB in WAMP. But I want to use Yii Framework. Getting different search results for PHP and Yii is confusing me.

Comment: I think it doesnt matter which framework you are using you have to just configure mongodb in place of mysql nothing else.